# How to remove index.php in codeigniter's code?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I want to remove index.php from url in codeigniter . So in user guide, there is way to do it by editing .htaccess.But my host do not allow to edit it. Is there any way to do with codeigniter's code? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but if you cannot do a URL re-write via .htaccess file then it's pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm afraid it's not possible. CodeIgniter (or browsers in general, for that matter) need an index file, by editing the .htaccess file you tell the browser not to show the 'index.php' part, but it's still there. Removing the index.php file itself is silly since your website won't work without it.

Answer (score 1):

put the following code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

and put `$config['index_page'] = '';` in config file instead of **`$config['index_page'] = '';`**
put the `.htaccess` near to `index.php` out of system and application folders

Answer (score -1):

I dont think there is a way to do it without editing the htaccess file.