# CodeIgniter remove index.php displays 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, routes

I know that this subject has been seen many times here, but I didn't see any of them solving my issue here...

I have an application that is working with Codeigniter. I try to remove the index.php in the URL, but it seems I'm cursed today.

Here's what I have in my config.php file :

```
$config['base_url']   = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/";
$config['index_page']    = "";
$config['uri_protocol']  = 'AUTO';
```

And here's my .htacess (such as CI suggests) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

With this, I'm unable to remove the index.php in the URL. In fact, it removes it well, but I have a pretty 404 then on the screen.

I checked the `phpinfos()` to see if the mod_rewrite was rightly activated, and there's no problem on this side.

**EDIT**

I checked my apache logs, and here's what I have :

```
[Wed Jul 18 12:27:08 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: [PATH]/trunk/user
```

The real path should be :

```
[PATH]/trunk/application/controllers/user
```

I saw that all this stuff is setup in the index.php file, but it seems that it's never called...

Could anyone suggests me something please to solve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Take a look at my answer on an other similar question: 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052294/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-code/11054045#11054045

Comment: What is the request URL you are entering? I'm assuming you're entering something like http://server.com/controllername/user, right?

Comment: user is my controller. but yes, i'm calling something like host/user/login

Comment: @LeventeNagy I already tried this tutorial, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

The first condition makes sure the request isn't for a valid file and the second makes sure it isn't for a valid directory. All requests for files or folders that don't actually exist in the file system are sent through index.php.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still have my 404. But the redirect is OK, it removes well the index.php (such as with the htaccess in my post).

Comment: You didn't delete the index.php file did you?

Comment: Problem solved. It was in the apache configuration of the Virtualhost. I added `Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews` and it worked !

Answer (score -1):

You can't block access to the index.php page as it is the main page that CI works off of.

Comment: He's not trying to block access to it, but to remove it from displaying in the URI.

Comment: In fact the real error is my 404. The index.php is removing well from the URL.