# Not working my .htaccess and config files

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I changed to the config file and .htaccess files. following files,

**Config.php**

> ```
> $config['base_url'] = BASE_URL;
> $config['index_page'] = '';
> $config['uri_protocol']   = 'REQUEST_URI';
> ```

**.htaccess**

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteBase /52322/
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

Error occur  **The requested URL /52322/login/ was not found on this server.**

**Please help me.**

herewith I have attached for a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove index.php in codeigniter's code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052294/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-code)

Comment: Thanks I will check @Sanu0786

Comment: But not working for me

Comment: Any issue in above my code. Please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in `.htaccess` and do `$config['base_url'] = '';`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and if above code not working , then you can refer this [old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this according indicated in you folder. i hope it should work 100%.

> config > Config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'Your Folder Path';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

> Root Folder > .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^/(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

> Root Folder > system > .htaccess

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

> Root Folder > application > .htaccess

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Please make sure you have actually enabled mod_rewrite. At your terminal prompt, enter the following:

**sudo a2enmod rewrite
`and restart the apache`**

**sudo service apache2 restart**

**2)** And edit the None to All

> AllowOverride **None** ---> AllowOverride **All**

sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After that, it will work properly.